# My attempt to follow Tatuzawa and Iseki strategy to get a bound for $\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}-\pi(x)$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion, summation-method

I don't know if this exercise is in the literature, where $Li(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$ is **the logarithmic integral** and $\pi(x)$ is the **prime counting function**

> **Question.** Compute a *good* bound for $$ \left|Li(x)-\pi(x) \right| $$ by using summation methods, Möbius inversion, Shapiro's tauberian theorem, bounding integrals and the statement of the **Prime Number theorem**. **Many thanks.**

I know that it is an unsolved problem to prove that it is $O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$, but I don't know what of the following sum of terms it is impossible get as a previous big oh term $O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$. Notice that I don't know what cancellations could be in the **sum of terms**. Neiher I don't know what are the techniques employed in the deduction of the best bounds for previous difference. I am inspired in Apostol's words of **section 4.11** (see bellow the reference) in a attempt, I say myself, to follow **Tatuzawa and Iseki strategy**.

**By specialization** with $F(x)=1$, thus $G(x):= \left[ x \right] \log x$ in **Apostol's Theorem 4.17** (Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory (Springer)), dividing by $\log^2 x$, when $x\geq 2$ and after integrating
$$Li(x)+\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)}{\log^2 t}dt=\int_2^x\frac{\sum_{n\leq t}\mu(n) \left[ \frac{t}{n} \right] \log\frac{t}{n}}{\log^2 t}dt,$$
where $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$ is the **second Chebyshev's function** with  $\Lambda(n)$ the **von Mangoldt function**, and $\mu(n)$ is the **Möbius function**, with $ \left[ x \right] $ as we know the **integer part function**. I know to do the following computations, if there are no mistakes, applying the **Prime Number theorem** (I say the $O(1)$ term), for $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n) \left[ \frac{x}{n} \right] \log\frac{x}{n}$ that is equal to
$$x\log x \left(  O(1)+O \left( \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)\right) \right) -x\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n}+O \left( x\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)\log n\right) ,$$
I know that it is possible to get by summation bounds for more terms *.

**By a second specialization** of the cited theorem, $\tilde{F}(x)=x$ thus $\tilde{G}:=x\log x\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}$, and thus we know that we can get this $\tilde{G}$ in an asymptotic identity as $x\log^2x+\gamma x \log x+O(\log x)$, where $\gamma$ is the **Euler-Mascheroni constant**, then by the theorem for $x\geq 2$

$$\frac{x}{\log ^2 x}+\frac{x}{\log^2 x} \left(\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\tilde{G} \left( \frac{x}{n} \right) , $$

and combining with the known $\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}+O \left( \frac{x}{\log^2 x} \right) $, and the application of **Shapiro's tauberian theorem** to get the asymptotic for $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$, with the first specialization of the cited theorem 
$$ Li(x)-\pi(x) = \int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)}{\log^2 t}dt-\frac{x}{\log x}+\int_2^x\frac{\sum_{n\leq t}\mu(n) \left[ \frac{t}{n} \right] \log\frac{t}{n}}{\log^2 t}dt$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\tilde{G} \left( \frac{x}{n} \right)+O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^2 x} \right). $$

**To clarify my question** I say in * and here that I want check with my functions **or with different specializations**, how much we can say about the difference $ Li(x)-\pi(x)$. I know that I can use the triangle inequality but I've said perhaps my computations were not the best. **I would like to use the cited Theorem 4.17** to test it, with techniques of the kind that I've cited, on assumption of the statement of the Prime Number theorem. **My question can be read as: what is the term that can not get as $O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$ in my computations or well in yourself, as you want.**

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is the question. The prime number theorem tell us that $$\left|\pi(x)-\textrm{Li}(x)\right|\leq x\exp(-C\sqrt{\log(x)})$$ where $C>0$. Do you want to know why we need to get RH for the error $O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))$?

Comment: Very thanks much @MarcoCantarini I am asking about: 1) What is the term in RHS of last equation that can not be obtained as $O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$ or 2) improve my computations with cited methods and if it is possible using Apostol's Theorem 4.17 to get the best bounds for differences $\pm(Li(x)-\pi(x))$. If my approach has no mathematical meaning please do detailed discussion as an answer. Very thans much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your calculations you can't obtain the error $O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)
 $. If you use the PNT in this form $$\pi\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ you already have an error bigger than $O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)
 $. Note that for every $m\geq0
 $ we have that $O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{m}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $ is bigger than $O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)
 $. If we want obtain this error we have to assume RH (Riemann hypothesis). The first step is to prove that PNT is equivalent to the asymptotic $$\psi\left(x\right)\sim x,\, x\rightarrow\infty
 $$ and now from the truncated Perron's formula we can get (for more details see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/254a-notes-2-complex-analytic-multiplicative-number-theory/), exercise $11$ and proposition $12$) that $$\psi\left(x\right)=x-\sum_{\left|\gamma\right|\leq T}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}+O\left(\frac{x}{T}\log^{2}\left(xT\right)\right)
 $$ where $\rho=\beta+i\gamma
 $ are the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function and $T>1$. So if we assume RH (i.e. $\beta=\frac{1}{2}
 $) we get $$\psi\left(x\right)-x\ll x^{1/2}\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}\frac{1}{\gamma}+\frac{x}{T}\log^{2}\left(xT\right).
 $$ Note that the assumpion of RH is important here. Without this hypothesis we have to take $\max_{\beta}\left\{ x^{\beta}\right\} 
 $ and then use a estimaton from the free zero region of the Riemann Zeta function, and so a bigger error. So the best bound we can get (so the best exponent) is when $\beta=1/2$. Now since from the [Riemann-Von Mangoldt formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93von_Mangoldt_formula) and partial summation we can prove that $$\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}\frac{1}{\gamma}\ll O\left(\log^{2}\left(T\right)\right)
 $$ so $$\psi\left(x\right)-x\ll x^{1/2}\log^{2}\left(T\right)+\frac{x}{T}\log^{2}\left(xT\right)
 $$ and now if we take $T=x^{1/2}
 $ we get $$\psi\left(x\right)=x+O\left(x^{1/2}\log^{2}\left(x\right)\right).\tag{1}
 $$ The next thing to do is observe that, using Abel's summation, $$\pi_{1}\left(x\right):=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{\log\left(n\right)}=\frac{\psi\left(x\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\psi\left(t\right)}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt\tag{2}
 $$ so, using $(1)$ in $(2)$, we get $$\pi_{1}\left(x\right)=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)+O\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt\right)
 $$ $$=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right).\tag{3}
 $$ The last step is to observe that $$\pi_{1}\left(x\right)=\sum_{p^{m}\leq x}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{m\log\left(p\right)}=\pi\left(x\right)+O\left(\pi\left(x^{1/2}\right)\right)
 $$ and since $\pi\left(x^{1/2}\right)\leq x^{1/2}
 $, so smaller than the error in $(3)$, we obtain $$\pi\left(x\right)=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right).$$

**Note:** This proof is classical and it was taken from Davenport, "Multiplicative number theory", second edition.

Comment: It is incredible, I'm sure that in next months I undertand it more. Very thanks much for such effort, it isn't a [+50], should be [+500]. I pay the bounty in 14 hours.

Comment: @user243301 If you want more details please tell me.

Comment: You are a good man, very thanks much. I will do when I know with more detail Perron's method and Riemann-Von Mangoldt formula, when I have more abilities.